# How to split a very long equation (using AMSMATH package)?

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, breqn

I'm trying to split up the following equation so that it fits the margins of my document, so far I have:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} 

\begin{equation}
0 = n_1^3 n_2 n_3^2(\lambda+\mu)^2 +n_1 n_2^3 n_3^2(\lambda + \mu)^2  + (\lambda + \mu)(\mu - \rho c^2)n_1^3 n_2 + (\lambda + \mu)(\mu - \rho c^2) n_1 n_2^3 + n_1 n_2 n_3^2 (\lambda + \mu)(\mu - \rho c^2) + n_1 n_2 (\mu- \rho c^2)^2 - n_1^3 n_2 n_3^2 (\lambda + \mu)^2 - n_1 n_2^3 n_3^2 (\lambda + \mu)^2 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

How do I make the equation split so that it fits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have eight summands on the right-hand side, split them two for each line:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
0 ={}&
n_1^3 n_2 n_3^2(\lambda+\mu)^2 +n_1 n_2^3 n_3^2(\lambda + \mu)^2 \\
&+ (\lambda + \mu)(\mu - \rho c^2)n_1^3 n_2 + (\lambda + \mu)(\mu - \rho c^2) n_1 n_2^3 \\
&+ n_1 n_2 n_3^2 (\lambda + \mu)(\mu - \rho c^2) + n_1 n_2 (\mu- \rho c^2)^2 \\
&- n_1^3 n_2 n_3^2 (\lambda + \mu)^2 - n_1 n_2^3 n_3^2 (\lambda + \mu)^2
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice trick with `={}` to get the right indentation on the later lines!

Comment: @Andrew A different trick is having `&=` in the first line and `&\qquad+` in the later ones.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use an `align` environment coupled with some `\notag` commands to prevent multiple equation numbers and some `\quad`'s for spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

  \begin{align}
  0&= n_1^3 n_2 n_3^2(\lambda+\mu)^2 +n_1 n_2^3 n_3^2(\lambda + \mu)^2
      +(\lambda + \mu)(\mu - \rho c^2)n_1^3 n_2\notag\\
    &\quad +(\lambda + \mu)(\mu - \rho c^2) n_1 n_2^3
      + n_1 n_2 n_3^2 (\lambda + \mu)(\mu - \rho c^2) + n_1 n_2 (\mu- \rho c^2)^2 \\
    &\quad - n_1^3 n_2 n_3^2 (\lambda + \mu)^2 - n_1 n_2^3 n_3^2 (\lambda + \mu)^2\notag
  \end{align}

\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]